# CKEditor for Drupal 7 does not show the page contents

Tags: wysiwyg

This page http://sunsethill-ubud.com/bistro contents some text. When I look at it as admin, I can use the Edit tab. But if I click this tab, I get an empty page in CKEditor: [image]

I tried playing with or without additional modules, with the version of jQuery, with uninstalling and installing again CKEditor, and so on. Probably the problem is very simple, but I don't see any solution.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. In my numerous attempts, I had checked the wysiwyg filter in the configuration page of CKEditor. I unchecked it, and everything is OK now.